# understanding body parameters in javascript

Tags: javascript, express

im having difficulty understanding how form data are taken in javascript. For example:

```
firstName: req.body.firstName || null,
                lastName: req.body.lastName || null
```

are firstName and lastName id's from the html used to identify what field the data is coming from?

Thank you!

Comment: Impossible to say by just looking at this part of the code. Request bodies can contain arbitrary text which needs to be parsed by the appropriate parser. However, when a form is submitted, the name and values of all form control elements are serialized to a string with the structure `input=value&input=value&...` . So yes, those names *could* correspond to form control element names. Looking at the client code/markup that makes the request would clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't really tell based on what you posted, if it is a direct form post (and not AJAX), then the data will come from `input`/`select` elements with those respective names, e.g.

```
<form method="POST" action="/express/endpoint">
   <input type="text" name="firstName" />
   <input type="text" name="lastName" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

This can also be sent manually via AJAX:

```
fetch('/express/endpoint', {
    body: JSON.stringify({ firstName: 'foo', lastName: 'bar' }),
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    method: 'POST'
}).then(function(response) {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There will likely be some sort of form parsing done that turns the `name` or other identifying fields into request parameters, such as

`...url.../?firstName=bob&lastName=dobbs`

From http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req

> The req object represents the HTTP request and has properties for the
>   request query string, parameters, body, HTTP headers, and so on. In
>   this documentation and by convention, the object is always referred to
>   as req (and the HTTP response is res) but its actual name is
>   determined by the parameters to the callback function in which you’re
>   working.

Answer (score 0):

- Check if your `firstName` and `lastName` spelling as the name attribute in `<input>` in `.html` forms is exactly the same or not.
- Install **body-parser** to fetch input from forms: `npm i body-parser`
- Require it in your `.js` file like this:

  ```
  Const bodyParser=require("body-parser");
  Const app=express();
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded{extended:true});
  ```